# bib database into bibtex/bib using l3build

Tags: l3build

I would like to use `l3build` to build a biblatex support package. I don't use `.ins` and `.dtx` files. My sourcefiles will be the following:

```
biblatex-support-package
|- files.bbx
|- files.cbx
|- files.dbx
|- files.lbx
|- file-doc.tex
|- file-example.bib
```

I would like the biblatex database to be installed in bibtex/bib/.. instead of the `doc` tree.
I have made several attempts (including using the `tdslocations` variable) but to no avail.

**Update after the response of @Joseph Wright**

The content of `build.lua` is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env texlua

-- Build script for biblatex-test package

module = "biblatex-test"

installfiles = {"*.bbx", "*.cbx", "*.dbx", "*.lbx"}
sourcefiles =  {"*.bbx", "*.cbx", "*.dbx", "*.lbx", "*.bib"}
unpackfiles = {}
tdslocations = {"bibtex/bib/"..module.."/*.bib"}
```

Comment: I'll address the question when I get a demo set up, but can I ask _why_ you want the example database in the 'live' tree? `bibtex/bib` makes the file generally available, but that only makes sense for a very small number of generic BibTeX databases.

Comment: My biblatex database contains items of `jurisdiction` entrytype and the package defines this non-standard entrytype. For this reason I think it's useful to make the bib file avalaible.

Comment: Also, I too need to have access to the bib file from my LOCALTEXMF, in order to do the various tests (package construction is at a very early stage of development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what you've tried, but

```lua
installfiles = {"*.cbx", "*.bbx","*.bib"}
sourcefiles = installfiles
tdslocations = {"bibtex/bib/" .. module .. "/*.bib"}
```

should work in a generic sense.

Comment: So, the bib file should be set into `installfiles` and not into `soucefiles`... good to know

Comment: @matteo339 No, they are the same here as you are not using a `.dtx`: see my second code line

Comment: So @JosephWright if I understand correctly 1) into `installfiles` should be listed all the files that do **not** concern the typesetting of the documentation (files that l3build will put in the LOCAL dir) 2) in the absence of the `.dtx` file there should be correspondence between `installfiles` and `sourcefiles`